# rc-local.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'

Tags: command-line, 20.04, systemd, vps

I want to active UDPGW port for calling and gaming in my VPS server, I did this commands for my previous two VPS and it worked fine.

```
sudo wget -O /usr/bin/badvpn-udpgw "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/daybreakersx/premscript/master/badvpn-udpgw64"
sudo touch /etc/rc.local
sudo nano /etc/rc.local

----------------------
#!/bin/sh -e
screen -AmdS badvpn badvpn-udpgw --listen-addr 127.0.0.1:7300
exit 0
----------------------

chmod +x /etc/rc.local
sudo systemctl status rc-local.service
sudo chmod +x /usr/bin/badvpn-udpgw
sudo screen -AmdS badvpn badvpn-udpgw --listen-addr 127.0.0.1:7300
reboot
sudo lsof -i -P -n | grep LISTEN
```

but now in my third VPS say this :

```
systemd[1]: Starting /etc/rc.local Compatibility...
rc.local[458]: /etc/rc.local: 2: screen: not found
systemd[1]: rc-local.service: Control process exited, code=exited, status=127/n/a
systemd[1]: rc-local.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
systemd[1]: Failed to start /etc/rc.local Compatibility.
```

What's problem and how I can fix this? I'm using Ubuntu 20.04

**Update**: When I'm use `sudo systemctl status rc-local.service`
show this :

```
* rc-local.service - /etc/rc.local Compatibility
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/rc-local.service; enabled-runtime; vendor preset: enabled)
    Drop-In: /usr/lib/systemd/system/rc-local.service.d
             `-debian.conf
     Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Sat 2023-05-27 10:40:31 EEST; 5 days ago
       Docs: man:systemd-rc-local-generator(8)
```

Comment: Is the `screen` program actually installed on your system?

Comment: yes , I'm used apt install screen and installed well

Comment: So do you get a different result if you use the full path `/usr/bin/screen` in the rc.local file?

Comment: no , I did it but again say this

Comment: Please [edit] your question with any new information - it's hard to read in comments

Comment: ok wait this is my first time I'm ask a question in stack :)

Comment: What is in your dropin file? I mean under /usr/lib/systemd/system/rc¬local. service. d/

Comment: Is Empty actually

Comment: Then remove it.

Comment: How should I remove?